# Barcode printer Zebra 105LS - text below barcode

Tags: barcode, zpl

I have simple label created in ZPL language for Zebra printer.
I want to enlarge the size of the text below the barcode.
I tried to find solution in web and I used command ^ADN,40 - text was moved to the left position.

My label is here:
 http://sunpic.me/vIzoilyu/barcodemale.jpg

```
^XA^JZN
^BY3^FS
^FO68,35^ADN,40^FD TRW ORS 34186401A^FS
^FO30,69^GB568,0,6^FS
^FO30,55^GB0,20,6^FS
^FO591,55^GB0,20,6^FS
^FO49,83
^BC,126,Y,N,N,N
^FD>;8640>61AAH44300E
^FS
^PQ1,,,
^XZ
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the ZPL code to print a barcode without human readable content:

```
^XA
^FXAutorizacao de Usuario
^FO50,35
^BY4,10,100
^BC,126,N,N,N,N
^FD0123456789
^FS
^CF0,40
^FO50,200^GB700,1,3^FS
^CF0,50
^FO50,220^FDBRUNO LEITAO^FS
^XZ
```

You can also test it online

[Labelary Online ZPL Viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFXAutoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20Usu%C3%A1rio%0A%5EFO50%2C35%0A%5EBY4%2C10%2C100%0A%5EBC%2C126%2CN%2CN%2CN%2CN%0A%5EFD0123456789%0A%5EFS%0A%5ECF0%2C40%0A%5EFO50%2C200%5EGB700%2C1%2C3%5EFS%0A%5ECF0%2C50%0A%5EFO50%2C220%5EFDBRUNO%20CESAR%20LEITAO%5EFS%0A%5EXZ%22)

Answer (score 0):

According to Zebra's ZPL docs:

> The font specified by command ^A is used only once for that ^FD entry.
>   If a value for ^A is not specified again, the default ^CF font is used
>   for the next ^FD entry.

So, I suggest you to try the following code:

```
^XA^JZN
^BY3^FS
^FO68,35^ADN,40^FD TRW ORS 34186401A^FS
^FO30,69^GB568,0,6^FS
^FO30,55^GB0,20,6^FS
^FO591,55^GB0,20,6^FS
^FO49,83
^BC,126,Y,N,N,N
^ADN,40^FD>;8640>61AAH44300E
^FS
^PQ1,,,
^XZ
```

If necessary, you can also change the "D" font by another bigger bitmapped font, as "F", "Q", etc.

Another suggestion:

```
^XA^JZN
^BY3^FS
^CFD,40^FO68,35^FD TRW ORS 34186401A^FS
^FO30,69^GB568,0,6^FS
^FO30,55^GB0,20,6^FS
^FO591,55^GB0,20,6^FS
^FO49,83
^BC,126,Y,N,N,N
^FD>;8640>61AAH44300E
^FS
^PQ1,,,
^XZ
```